# Dual boot problem: different disks and boot mode

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

I have a problem while booting on Windows 10.

I have :

- Ubuntu budgie: /dev/sd**a**1 (UEFI)
- Windows 10 : /dev/sd**b**1 (Legacy)

I can only boot to Ubuntu in UEFI mode and when I change to legacy boot I get 'grub rescue'.

I tried `os-prober` and `update-grub` nothing changed.

I hope that you can help me get back windows 10 without reinstalling it.

Thanks.

Comment: That's how it is. Different OSes installed in different modes need different modes set in order to boot one or another. And if you have UEFI always install in UEFI mode, especially Windows 10. It may not make much of a difference for a desktop Linux but it impacts Windows 8 or newer performance negatively when running in Legacy mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your BIOS, and then change the Boot Mode from UEFI to Legacy First.